# Get an object from a bucket in riak without knowing its key

Tags: riak

I am using a riak bucket to store a list of messages, using a UUID as the key and a json message as value. This is working fine.

What I need is an efficient way to **get a single message from the bucket without knowing its key**, at least in one of these two scenarios:

1. Get the last inserted object (this is my prefered approach).
2. Get a random object from the bucket (if the first alternative is not possible).

Is there any efficient way to achieve that?

I think one alternative could be to retrieve the keys in the bucket and then get the first one. But this means making two calls to riak, one to obtain all the keys (just to discard all but one) and a second one to obtain the object. It does not seem very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Riak is a key-value store, the by far most efficient way to retrieve data is through the keys. Listing or retrieving all keys in a bucket, even if you only end up using the one returned first, is one of the least efficient operations you can perform as it causes Riak to scan ALL keys in the system (not just the bucket), and it is usually recommended NEVER to use this on a production system.

The most efficient way to get the last inserted object would probably be to store the id in a separate, known record in a different bucket. This would however require you to perform two writes on every insert and two reads for every read, but would do so in the most efficient way. You could possibly implement a post-commit hook (would have to be in Erlang as it is not currently not possible to write records using JavaScript functions) on the bucket containing messages to get the system to perform the update for you, which would remove the need for the last write.

If you write a lot of data to the bucket containing messages, you may want to adjust the separate bucket so that it does not allow multiple values and that the last value wins. This way you would reduce the risk of having lots of siblings created due to frequent updates to this single record across the system. This would always give you one of the last written records, but not necessarily the last one (especially if you frequently write messages to the database), as Riak does not support any type of atomicity and is an eventually consistent database.

You could also create one or more secondary indexes if you are using the leveldb backend, and use this to limit your scan to only recent records, which would be more efficient than a scann of all keys. You could then either select the most recent key or a random one through mapreduce, but this would be much less efficient than the previously described approach.

I can not think of any efficient way to retrieve a random record in a bucket from Riak unless you know the range of keys you have inserted and can decide randomly on the client which one to get. One way to do this would be to generate all keys in sequence rather than using a UUID, but that is naturally not a good idea in a highly concurrent distributed system.

Comment: Thanks. I mark your answer as accepted as it is a good explanation of why riak is not the best tool to be used as a queue or, in general, to make operations with objects whose key is not known.

Answer (score 0):

1st task is pretty easy to implement:

- Add [post-commit hook](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/references/appendices/concepts/Commit-Hooks/#Post-Commit-Hooks) that will write the last inserted key to some predefined key/bucket place
- Get the key from that predefined key/bucket and issue a get query using them

It's still two operations but both are just gets that are fast. Plus additional overhead on hook but nothing too heavy either.

2nd scenario is also easy, but it is way too inefficient to be used practically:

- Get all keys (extremely expensive operation)
- Pick random
- Issue get

Comment: Thanks Ivan. The first task is not so easy, because when the last inserted key is recovered, I have to remove this object, and a new key should occupy its place as the "new last inserted key". I was planning to use this bucket more or less like a queue.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the same scenario. In My scenario I have to save the users. For that I required an auto increment Id. So what I did is, I placed the last inserted key in a separate bucket as like mentioned by "Christian Dahlqvist", every time I want to insert new record I fetch the last inserted key from that key bucket. Here we have only one value in that bucket with the key as "LastKey" which is always known to us. And I incremented the key based on the fetched key and again updated the key bucket. So always the key bucket contains the latest key in it.